# Weird black fading rectangles appearing on my monitor... Any clue?

Tags: display, hardware-failure

Around 3 months ago I started noticing these weird black-faded lines that appear in the left side of my monitor. I'm 100% sure the issue is on my monitor because when i take a screen capture while the lines are displayed, I get no lines in the capture. They are like evolved dead pixels haha.

When I turn off and turn on the monitor, the lines are gone, but I was curious about what kind of problem does my monitor has. Take a look at the pic I took of the issue:

[image: 1]

Have you experienced something similar? I'd like to know if the problem is bound to be solved or if its just a monitor defect.

More info: LCD tv, LG model M2262D 22" connected to the pc through HDMI cable.

Comment: What sort of monitor is it? CRT or LCD? Also, what kind of cable connects it to your computer?

Comment: @cpast It's an LCD. It's connected to the PC via HDMI cable.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hardware fault. You should have contacted the manufacturer as soon as you noticed it- once it's out of warranty you'll be stuck with it.